# Debug ruby algorithm

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to capitalize the second letter of every word in a string. For example, if the string is "how are you", it should return [0,R,0], however I'm getting ['nil','nil','nil']. Why am I getting nil? Is there something I'm doing wrong?

```
def capitalize(string)
  words = string.split(" ")
  index = 0
  words.each do|word|
    break if index == words.length
    p word[index][1].inspect
    index += 1
  end
end

capitalize("how are you")
```

Comment: Just alternative way that might interest you `string = "how are you"`
then `string.split.map.with_index{ |s,i| i%2 != 0 ? s[1].capitalize : s=0 }`

Answer (score 3):

Let's take a look what's happening here:

```
index = 0
words.each do |word|
  break if index == words.length
  p word[index][1].inspect
  index += 1
end
```

In the first iteration, `word` will be `"how"` and `index` will be 0, so you're doing `p word[0][1].inspect`. `"how"[0]` is `"h"`, and `"h"[1]` is `nil` (because the string `"h"` only has one character).

In the second iteration, `word` is `"are"` and `index` is 1. `"are"[1]` is `"r"` and `"r"[1]` is, again, `nil`.

And so on. In every iteration you're taking a single character from `word` and then trying to get the second character of that string, which will always be `nil`.

I suspect this is what you were trying to do:

```
index = 0
loop do
  break if index == words.length
  p words[index][1]
  index += 1
end
```

See the difference? It prints `words[index][1]`, not `word[index][1]`, and keeps looping forever until `index == words.length` is true.

However, since Ruby has `Enumerable#each`, you can let it do the work of iterating over `words` for you, and you don't need to worry about `index` at all. This is what you want:

```
words.each do |word|
  p word[1]
end
```

P.S. You'll notice that I used `p word[1]`, not `p word[1].inspect`. The `p` method will automatically call `inspect` on each of its arguments. If you do `p word[1].inspect`, you're basically doing `puts word[1].inspect.inspect`.

Comment: Thanks for you help! Got it now.

Comment: Glad to help! Feel free to accept my answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: ...but there is no rush to select an answer, and OP doesn't want to discourage other answers or short-circuit those still working on answers. Many on SO wait at least a couple of hours.

Comment: Shihan, click on the grey checkmark to the left of the answer you want to accept. See the [SO faq](http://stackoverflow.com/help) for coverage of other things you need to know.

Answer (score 2):

@Jordan has done a good job going through your code and explaining the problems.

One option would be to use a regular expression:

```
R = /
    (?<=     # begin a positive lookbehind
      \b     # match a word break
      [a-z] # match a lower-case letter
    )        # end positive lookbehind
    [a-z]   # match a lower-case letter
    /ix      # case-insensitive (i) and free-spacing regex definition (x) modes

def capitalize(str)
  str.gsub(R) { |c| c.upcase }
end

capitalize("how are you")
  #=> "hOw aRe yOu"
```

You could of course write:

```
def capitalize(str)
  str.gsub(/(?<=\b[a-z])[a-z]/i) { |c| c.upcase }
end
```

Another way of writing the regex is:

```
R = /
    \b    # match a word break
    [a-z] # match a lower-case letter
    \K    # forget everything matched so far
    [a-z] # match a lower-case letter
    /ix   # case-insensitive (i) and free-spacing regex definition (x) modes
```

Answer (score 1):

One-liner should be presented here :)

```
"how are you".split(" ").map{ |w| w[1].capitalize }
=> ["O", "R", "O"]
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple and clean solution is this

```
def capitalize(string)
  words = string.split(" ")
  words.each_with_index.map do |word, index|
    if index % 2 == 0
        0
    else
        word[1].swapcase
    end
  end
end

capitalize("how are you")
```

You can try it out here https://repl.it/Bwyk/2

Comment: Sorry about the typo, it's not 0's, the return should be [O,R,O], replaced with 'Letter" O's